# Horizontally flip an MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, cgaffinetransform

Is it possible to flip the video part of an MPMoviePlayerController only and leave the player's control the same as it is? When I try to flip a video it also flips the controls.

```
CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
trans = CGAffineTransformScale(trans, -1, 1);
[MoviePlayer.view setTransform:trans];
```

Comment: Your above code has solved my major Problem !!!! thanx bro

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UIView* Flipview = [[UIView alloc]init];
    for (UIView* view in [theMovie.view subviews]) 
    {
        Flipview=view;
        NSLog(@"%@",view);
    }



     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
            [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:Flipview cache:YES];

            [UIView commitAnimations];
```

change self.view with movieplayerview and see if its working.

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: do you want to change video on flip??

Comment: I would like to flip the video but not its controls.